# how to pass load control in exoplayer 2.11.8 version

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using `exoplayer 2.11.8` version. In this version, they have changed the lot of methods. By Searching their docs, I build the `Exoplayer`.

Here's the Code:

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this
                        , getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString()));
       
LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                .setAllocator(new DefaultAllocator(true, 16))
                .setBufferDurationsMs(MIN_BUFFER_DURATION,
                        MAX_BUFFER_DURATION,
                        MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER,
                        MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER)
                .setTargetBufferBytes(-1)
                .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(true).createDefaultLoadControl();
// Create a progressive media source pointing to a stream uri.
MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(audio_url));
// Create a player instance.
simpleExoPlayer =  new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
```

I want to pass the `load control` to exoplayer. In older versions,  `Load control` was passed like below,

```
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();

DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder().setBufferDurationsMs(32*1024, 64*1024, 1024, 1024).createDefaultLoadControl();
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
```

In newer version, they have changed the code for creating exoplayer instance which is shown below

```
simpleExoPlayer =  new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
```

In here, i don't know where to pass the `load control`. I searched their `exoplayer` docs. But there is no example for passing `load control`.
Please help me and provide some solution to pass `load control` to `exoplayer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check following code.

```
DefaultRenderersFactory renderersFactory;
    
DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder().setBufferDurationsMs(25000, 50000, 1500, 2000).build();
                        
@DefaultRenderersFactory.ExtensionRendererMode int extensionRendererMode = DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER;

renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this) .setExtensionRendererMode(extensionRendererMode);          

player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context, renderersFactory)
                                    .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
                                    .setLoadControl(loadControl)
                                    .build();
```